# I want to bind product from database and want to display in grid in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Now I am doing this with html but I want it with `MVC Grid` option. So anybody can help me on this also when changing quantity in grid, I want to update also row total and column total.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `table` object based on your line items.

```
<table>
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.LineItems.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
       <td><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Index", new { id = Model.LineItems[i].ID})">Details</a> @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LineItems[i].ID)</td>
       <td>........</td>
       <td>........</td>
       .
       .
       .
       <td>@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.LineItems[i].Qty, new { @class="form-input"})</td>
    </tr> 
}
</table>
```

So now when you submit your model, your LineItems Array will be populated